# Table with JSON table inside

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#temp_client]
(
    [client_name] [varchar](200) NULL, 
    [client_datev_json] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
)

ISNERT INTO [#temp_client] 
VALUES ('Client AA', '[{"datev": [  { "ktonr" : 20203,"name": ""} ]}]')

INSERT INTO [#temp_client] 
VALUES ('Client BB', '[{"datev": [  { "ktonr" : 20305,"name": ""}  , { "ktonr" : 20295,"name": ""} ]}]')

INSERT INTO [#temp_client] 
VALUES ('Client CC', '[{"datev": [  { "ktonr" : 20268,"name": ""} ]}]')
```

I'm trying to write a query which would produce this output:

```
client_name | ktonr
------------+-------
Client AA   | 20203
Client BB   | 20305
Client BB   | 20295
Client CC   | 20268
```

I was trying with CTE/WITH and CROSS APPLY, but seems like I don't handle it quite well. Maybe someone here is willing to help.

Comment: JSON has no tables, it has schemaless objects and arrays. Period. If you need to treat the contents as a table, you should extract the data to a proper table. JSON and XML support is meant for storing data that has no schema and doesn't need frequent querying. You gain *nothing* by using a JSON string to store a table, lose the ability to query the data and end up eating up a lot more memory

Comment: You can't pass JSON to SQL Server and expect it to infer what you want. You need to use the JSON functionality SQL Server has; specifically you appear to need `OPENJSON` here.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do, extract the data (OK, not table)  from the JSON object, so I can perform a join on that ktonr value. I have a table with ktonr and I need to find the matching client_name , with one client_name having multiple ktonr .I was able to create views that would display JSON data stored in tables and render the data as table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT tc.client_name
      ,A.ktonr
FROM #temp_client tc
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(tc.client_datev_json,'$[0].datev')
            WITH(ktonr INT) A;
```

the idea in short:

- We use `OPENJSON()` to get into your JSON string.
- We use the JPath `$[0].datev` because your JSON looks like an *array of objets* although there is just one single object and
- the `datev`-property is an *array of objects* itself.
- We can use the `WITH`-clause to get the `ktonr` typed and directly.